# Geting all points (coordinates) from VGPath?

Tags: c++, svg, path, points, openvg

I use MonkSVG for drawing and it stores points inside a variable of type `typedef VGHandle VGPath;`

I need to find the smallest rect which contains all the points of VGPath. So I need to get all the points from this variable. I don't need additional modifiers from SVG file such as "move_to", "line_to" and e.t.c.

As I see separate points could be stored using the following functions from OpenVG/MonkVG:

- vgAppendPathData
- vguRect
- ...

Comment: I tried vgPathBounds and it solves my current problem, but it doesn't allow to get all points. Here is a quick reference card for openVG: http://www.khronos.org/files/openvg-quick-reference-card.pdf